# hide divs correctly when load page

Tags: jquery

Hi everyone i have a script that hide div´s, these script is this

```
<script>
       $( document ).ready(function() { 
          $('#contenedor-no').hide();
           $('.caja-cobertura').hide();

          $('#shopi').on("click", function() {
            $('#contenedor-no').show(); 
            $('.escondido .caja1-orden').hide();
          });

          $('#cober').on("click", function() {
             //oculto mediante id
          });
        });

  </script>
```

when i load my page, firts appear all div´s are hidding and quickly load the rest of page how can solved this, cause isnt pretty my web page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In starting, your Divs are all visible and the rendering happens like that. Then the script you have written is doing extra work of hiding the elements.

Your better choice is to keep those divs hidden by default and only show when required. You can put display : none in the markup.

Something along these lines :

```
<div id="contenedor-no" style="display:none;">some content</div>
```

So your code will become something like this :

```
<script>
       $( document ).ready(function() { 

          $('#shopi').on("click", function() {
            $('#contenedor-no').show(); 
            $('.escondido .caja1-orden').hide();
          });

          $('#cober').on("click", function() {
             //oculto mediante id
          });
        });

  </script>
```

You are using HIDE correctly so hide the element when some click is happening. The only change is that we removed the hiding of div on page load.

Comment: Thx with this can solved my error!, can u tell when is property use .hide jquery